# Opensaml validate vs ComponentSpace validation

Tags: java, .net, opensaml, component-space

I am using opensaml to sign my SAML and I am also successfully able to validate it using OpenSAML's SignatureValidator.

```
 SignatureValidator signValidator = new SignatureValidator( publicCredential );
  signValidator.validate( signature );
```

The IdP uses Component space to validate on their side however they are unable to  validate it using the same SAML and publicCertificate.

```
bool retVal = SAMLMessageSignature.Verify(samlResponseXml, x509Certificate);// returning false
```

The Signature algorithm in SAML is RSASHA1. From their logs we were able to see that the signature's hash value is different. Here are the logs:

http://pastebin.com/X27vUtbY

Answer (score 1):

The computed and expected hashes are different, as you say, which indicates the XML has been modified after signing. We have no known interoperability issues with OpenSAML so I suspect there's something else going on here.
It's hard to say what the issue is from the limited information. I suggest the SP contact us, including the full SAML log, and we should be able to resolve the issue.